# Cant get body background image or header image to display

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my body background image or my header image to display. I am sure it is something extremely simple but I have been googling and put it in just like my professor did and I still can't seem to figure it out.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background: #171717 url("assets/img/bg-tile.jpg") repeat-x;
}

#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  height: 140px;
  background: url("assets/img/header_1.jpeg");
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If you press f12 in your Browser and Go to Console, is there a error like Image Not found?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solves your issue

`background: #171717 url("/assets/img/bg-tile.jpg") repeat-x;`

Note I added a "/" at the start, for path relative to domain

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image paths are correct. Let's say you have your css is in `assets/css/styles.css` and your images are in `assets/images/`. The path from your CSS to the background image will need to be `"../images/image.jpg`.